# How to speed-up Geth transactions in private blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, mining, geth

I'm testing Ethereum smart contracts with `web3j` and `Geth`.
Geth is running with scripts like that:

```
PASSFILE=/var/folders/_l/kl9pdj2x50v7416j8htb6w740000gn/T/pwd6597172766860806720.tmp
DATADIR=/var/folders/_l/kl9pdj2x50v7416j8htb6w740000gn/T/geth808290308908087582
IPCPATH=/var/folders/_l/kl9pdj2x50v7416j8htb6w740000gn/T/geth808290308908087582/geth.ipc

geth --datadir $DATADIR account new --password $PASSFILE
geth --datadir $DATADIR \
    --ipcpath $IPCPATH \
    --dev \
    --rpc \
    --mine \
    --networkid 1999
```

(paths are generated in tests).

Smart contract wrappers are generated with `web3j-maven-plugin`.

The problem is that every `send()` invocation takes few seconds:

```
private TransactionReceipt deployFeature_() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Deploying feature ...");
    return contract.deployFeature(featureKey).send();
}
```

log (you can see 1 transaction took 16 seconds):

```
166955 [main] INFO FeatureTest - Deploying feature ...
182006 [main] INFO FeatureTest - Checking feature is listed ...
```

Web3j is connected over IPC:

```
web3 = Web3j.build(new UnixIpcService(ipcPath));
```

How can i speed-up invocations? If testing with `TestRPC` every invocations takes much less than a second! Since `Geth` is started with `--dev` it generates genesis file itself so i can't change difficulty. Also i can see blocks are mined very fast:

```
INFO [11-09|00:34:39] Commit new mining work                   number=9 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.000s
INFO [11-09|00:34:39] Successfully sealed new block            number=9 hash=b869ca…870644
INFO [11-09|00:34:39]  block reached canonical chain          number=4 hash=c758a0…a529af
INFO [11-09|00:34:39]  mined potential block                  number=9 hash=b869ca…870644
INFO [11-09|00:34:39] Commit new mining work                   number=10 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=84.12µs
INFO [11-09|00:34:40] Successfully sealed new block            number=10 hash=5e81a9…fc1364
INFO [11-09|00:34:40]  block reached canonical chain          number=5  hash=465c2b…78461a
INFO [11-09|00:34:40]  mined potential block                  number=10 hash=5e81a9…fc1364
```

For some reason invocations are not fast. What can i do?

Comment: try to start `geth --cache XXX` with proper cache value.  By default it's 128MB

Comment: i've just tried `--fast --cache=1024` but every transaction still lasts for ~ 15 seconds though blocks are mined ~ every 1 second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `web3j` feature/issue and you can change this behaviour:
https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/231

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to change the TransactionManager in a Contract:

```
// Using RawTransactionManager
TransactionManager transactionManager = new org.web3j.tx.RawTransactionManager(web3j, <credentials>, 40, 500);

// Or using ClientTransactionManager
TransactionManager transactionManager = new org.web3j.tx.ClientTransactionManager(web3j, "0x<fromAddress>", 40, 500);

// Now we'll poll every 500 ms for a transaction response
YourContract contract = YourContract.deploy("0x<contracAddress>", web3j,
        transactionManager, ManagedTransaction.GAS_PRICE, Contract.GAS_LIMIT,
        <initialValue>, <constructorParam1>,...);
```

I've got this example from [here](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/70#issuecomment-287215613).